# Go Gin - http "HEAD" request method

Tags: http, go, go-gin

I tried to set http method to "GET" if an incoming request method is "HEAD" in a middleware like below.

It looks like Gin recognizes this as "GET" request if I do curl -I,
but it responds with 404 as the attached log shows (the bottom one).

I just wanted to see if this works without implementing "HEAD" method in a router level.
Any advice?

```golang
func CORS() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }

        //  set http method to "GET" if an incoming request is "HEAD"
        if c.Request.Method == "HEAD" {
            c.Request.Method = "GET"
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

[gin's log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlAUB.png)

Comment: Not familiar with gin, but presumably route matching happens before any handlers run. Also, [sending a body in response to a HEAD request violates the HTTP spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.2), so treating GET and HEAD the same seems like a very dubious idea.

Comment: Peter is correct. If you declared the route as a `GET`, e.g. `r.GET("/", CORS(), handler)` and you send a `HEAD` request, it won't match. You might make this work by declaring the route as `r.Any`, but Peter's comment stands: it's best to not conflate GET and HEAD handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because gin middleware is a processing function obtained after route matching, middleware executes after route matching, so middleware cannot modify the route matching method.

By decorating a layer of http.Handler(gin.Engine), use http.Server middleware to modify the request method.

Note: There is no response body for the 'HEAD' request. If there is a response body after converting 'HEAD' to 'GET', which does not conform to the http protocol specification, it is recommended to register all the 'Get' processing functions with the 'Head' method.

```golang
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":8080",
        Handler:        http.Handler(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
            if r.Method == "HEAD" {
                r.Method = "GET"
            }
            router.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }),
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    s.ListenAndServe()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its good to know that gin's middleware executes after route matching. It seems to work with http.HandlerFunc(...), not with http.Handler, by the way.